# How do I back one and deselect when shift clicking selections? Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, selections

If I shift click to select different objects in illustrator and I click the wrong selection is there a way to go back one so I don't have to deselect and start from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply shift-click again to deselect the wrong object